# Codeigniter route webservice only calling default url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed Rest webservice for mobile platform. 
my webservice are

```
domain.com/new_task/index.php/Users/get_user
```

but one webservice called from mobile platform

```
domain.com/new_task/index.php/get_user_mob
```

right now mobile app is updated i cant change this webservice from mobile platform.
i just want automatically route this webservice on this url

```
domain.com/new_task/index.php/get_user_mob
```

please help me solve this problem

Comment: From the web service you can check if it’s getting called from the mobile. If yes then update your web service to internally call another new service.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to your routes.php in the config

$route['get_user_mob'] = 'Users/get_user';

it will make things work.

Comment: in case you need an explanation, feel free to comment.

Comment: try adding index.php in both.
$route['index.php/get_user_mob'] = 'index.php/Users/get_user';